# [ERROR]: {"code":"7","message":"No ssrResources.json file"} when deploying a SSR Next Js App ~ AMPLIFY

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify

When I try to deploy my Next JS app on Amplify I encounter this error. My build is 100% successful but I don't know why I am getting this error. I have set my app Service Role permission.

I am using Amplify website to deploy my Next JS application ( not with Amplify CLI)

LOG:

> 2021-09-29T04:42:25 [INFO]: Beginning deployment for application dh8mh8nkle4ny, branch:dev, buildId 0000000018
> 2021-09-29T04:42:26 [INFO]: Cannot find any generated SSR resources to deploy. If you intend for your app to be SSR, please check your app Service Role permissions. Otherwise, please check out our docs on how to setup your app to be detected as SSG (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/server-side-rendering-amplify.html#deploy-nextjs-app)
> 2021-09-29T04:42:26 [ERROR]: {"code":"7","message":"No ssrResources.json file"}

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

**ACTUAL OUTPUT:**
[image: ACTUAL OUTPUT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I fixed it by myself so the main issue was I was setting Next version: 11 which is not possible. As of today, we can either use 9,10 or the latest. So latest basically means version 11.